# Access External Hard Drive via network

Tags: nas

I want to access my simple wd passport device accessed over network (Ethernet or wifi) i am the only user who will be access the drive and os is ubuntu.

I was thinking of something like raspberry pi 3 but a USB to NAS converter option looks good to. what is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the software method. Try to use https://www.flexihub.com/. You can connect it through USB and get access from anywhere in your location.unfortunately commercial program, but if it is unprofitable to be, I think there are analogs.